# How to serialize class in custom library

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll

I have a class in my C# library:

```
public class PositiveLayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializableField]
    internal BezierPoint[] Bezier { get; private set; }

    public PositiveLayer()
    {
        Bezier = new BezierPoint[0];
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class BezierPoint
    {
        public Vector2 Target;
        public Vector2 Tangent;
    }
}
```

The Unity3D can see this class in my library and allows to add like a component to a some `GameObject` in the scene. But it lost a state in prefabs. How to provide serialization for classes inside C# library (.DLL)?
How should I change these classes to the Unity3D's editor could make a correct prefab to save this script state? Is it possible if my class locates inside `.dll` library? If it isn't, how can I separate it in inner and outter realizations to it was possible?

Comment: Serialize to what ? Json? Binary?

Comment: @Programmer, I just need to when the user drags his game object to make a prefab with my script, my script didn't lose value of its fields

Comment: You will likely have to implement `ISerializable` and deal with the `Bezier` details yourself.

Comment: I have never made constructors to MonoBehaviors, but it seems to me that you define new BezierPoint array in constructor and it's bit unclear to me who should set the values to the new BezierPoint array.

Comment: Actually, there should not be a constructor for MonoBehaviour. Or has Unity changed so that it is now allowed? Also setting an array to length 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can't serialize properties with Unity. Consider storing it in private field and expose it with your property getter.

Also, you can't use constructors with MonoBehaviours. Consider using Awake() method for initialization purposes. Take note that if you move your constructor code to Awake it will override your serialized value.

```
[SerializableField]
//default value if there is no serialized value available.
private BezierPoint[] bezier = new BezierPoint[0];

internal BezierPoint[] Bezier { get { return bezier; } }
```